# The Allure Of The Book

Tags: book

I am writing my dissertation on 'The Allure Of The Book' and i'll be focusing on; why consumers love books, why designers love books, what is it about the book that is held in such regard to the designer and any other relevant topics. If you could kindly provide me with your views and opinions or known facts with any links that may help me that would be great. Many thanks

Looking forward to your replies :)

Harley

Comment: Hi harley, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Although the question is an interesting one, I think it's a difficult fit for our community and the Stack Exchange model in general. The question naturally leads to opinion based answers. Could you maybe rephrase it so that answers will be less opinion based? Please see [help] for more info.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for ideas, literature review, or opinions (poll). Non of this is suited for the Stack Exchange format.

Answer (score 2):

Designers are obsessed with books because it is the most fundamental object in the field. Everything else is more or less ephemeral, ads are thrown away the next day, posters end up in the bin, flyers barely make it to the recipient's hand. Magazines and newspapers get thrown once read. Books however stay in shelves or on coffee tables. In other words objects in themselves.

Graphic design is all about making this for others to see (perhaps design in general). Designers are vain like that, even if there is a lot more to design than just making pretty things. Anyone trying to convince you of anything else are lying about how giddy they got the first time they saw something they made in print. Because of the limited lifespan of the other things designers make, the book becomes extra special due to it's much longer lifespan.

That said, PieBie makes a good point over, this question is a bit too open ended for this forum.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your views, this will help a lot.